# how to create folder and file in storage directory in android

Tags: android, android-storage

I wanted to create some folders and some files to `/storage/MyFolder/`.
I had tried to work on using `/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder` and it is working but i want to make hide under the storage root folder.

Is there any possible way for me to do this?

Comment: Try naming it `.MyFolder`...

Comment: Hi I'L'l thanks for the reply, i do know using .MyFolder will hidden file but is there anyway that i can create the folder like the directory "/storage/MyFolder" ? I don't want that user can be find it easily

Comment: try this tutorial...... https://www.dev2qa.com/android-read-write-external-storage-file-example/

Comment: you should not hide any files from user in the user-accessible storage. If you want to secure files from the user, use internal storage.

Comment: Hi @VladyslavMatviienko you are right Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can create **folder** like this in **External Storage** directory:

```
String folder_main = "NewFolder";

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
if (!f.exists()) {
f.mkdirs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//get path to external storage (SD card)
String iconsStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Abc/";
File sdIconStorageDir = new File(iconsStoragePath);

//create storage directories, if they don't exist

if(!sdIconStorageDir.exists()){
   sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: your answer is right , you just need to add check before this line 
if(!sdIconstorageDis.exists())
      sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();

Comment: ```Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ``` is deprecated and should not be used anymore. Use ```context.getExternalFilesDir(String type)``` instead